# v3 recaptcha bypass issue using website-bot

Tags: c#, bots, recaptcha, dotnet-httpclient, recaptcha-v3

I'm targeting a website which requires me to solve v3 + v2 captchas.

First I used automation tools such puppeeter and selenium, but since my entire goal and succesfull relies on speed, I refactored it to use only HTTP requests (GET/POST) with `HttpClient` which demonstrade the whole flow, and it was faster and more comfortable to do what I want.

Doing the flow as a human on the actual website, most of the time doesn't asks recaptcha v2 but only v3 which is all in background, but sometime does - probably when the v3 solution not enought to satisifed the system.

Doing the flow bases on HTTP calls per se, 100% of the times asks v3 and then v2.
**Doesn't matter what captcha solver service I used, what v3 score and action ("verify", "submit" etc) I mentioned** (in my first generation bot- using browser, selenium etc, it was asked v2 as well).

The tokens for v2, v3 passed inside the post body request it self, and I recognize when I asked for v2 or not (after submitting v3) based on the HTTP response from server.

There is no really problem with solving v2 in addition to v3, but since every second important in my flow, waiting for v2 solution takes very long time (30s-60s) compared to the v3 (5s-10s) and makes me fail, bottom line.

I don't put here the whole code because nothing realy to show.
it somethig like:

```
var captchaV3token = await CaptchaSolverAPI.SolveV3(param);

using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "URL"))
{
    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("g-recaptcha-response", captchaV3token),
    });

    var httpResponseMessage = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

I try to understand what am I missing, why it keeps ask me for v2 after I submitted the v3. If I'll understand how to satisified the system based only the v3, probably I'll score with my bot

Thanks